auto return value of parent class () operator for templated child class
I am wondering whether it is possible to have an operator in a non-templated parent class with an auto return value and a templated child class??
Here is an example:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class parent{
public:
  virtual ~parent(){};
  auto & operator()(const int i);
};
template<typename T>
class child:public parent{
protected:
  std::vector<T> X_;
public:
  child(std::vector<T> const &X):X_{X}{};
  T & operator()(const int i){
    return(X_[i]);
  }
};
auto & parent::operator()(const int i){
  if(auto * x=dynamic_cast<child<int>*>(this)){
    return((*x)(i));
  }else if(auto * x=dynamic_cast<child<double>*>(this)){
    return((*x)(i));
  }else{
    throw std::string("error");
  }
};
int main(){
  child Y1(std::vector<int>{5,10});
  child Y2(std::vector<double>{6,11});
  std::cout<<Y1(0)<<std::endl;
  parent * X=&Y1;
  std::cout<<(*X)(0)<<std::endl;
}

Currently I get: error: 'auto' in return type deduced as 'double' here but deduced as 'int' in earlier return statement
Any suggestions much appreciated.
A practical example arises when building a vector of parent pointers to child vectors:
int main(){
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<parent>> Z;
  Z.push_back(std::make_shared<child<int>>(std::vector<int>{5,10}));
  Z.push_back(std::make_shared<child<double>>(std::vector<double>{5,10}));
  std::cout<<(*Z[0])(1)<<std::endl;
}

A working solution to access elements of the child vector would be to drop the operator in the parent class and to resolve the pointer in a loop:
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class parent{
public:
  virtual ~parent(){};
};
template<typename T>
class child:public parent{
protected:
  std::vector<T> X_;
public:
  child(std::vector<T> const &X):X_{X}{};
  T & operator()(const int i){
    return(X_[i]);
  }
};
int main(){
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<parent>> Z;
  Z.push_back(std::make_shared<child<int>>(std::vector<int>{5,10}));
  Z.push_back(std::make_shared<child<double>>(std::vector<double>{5,10}));
  for(auto &x:Z){
    if(auto xx=std::dynamic_pointer_cast<child<int>>(x)){
      std::cout<<(*xx)(0)<<std::endl;
    }else if(auto xx=std::dynamic_pointer_cast<child<double>>(x)){
      std::cout<<(*xx)(0)<<std::endl;
    }
  }
}

But this would mean that throughout the code every loop iterating over Z must be reworked if a child is is being invoked with a previously unused template parameter (i.e. adding Z.push_back(std::make_shared<child<float>>(std::vector<float>{5,10})); to the code would require to manually extend the if branches in the subsequent loop).
The goal is to avoid this manual extension of the loop.

dynamic_cast is a runtime feature, but method return type must be determined at compile time.

thanks. so how to get the concept to work?

I don't think you can do it in a polymorphic way, because all types must be known at compile time of parent::operator().

The concept cannot work. The expression (*X)(0) must have some type at compile time. It cannot magically change type based on what X happens to point to at run time. Take a step back, describe the problem you are actually trying to solve. Currently this looks like an XY problem

If the second if branch in the parent operator is deleted it works. Of course then the return type will have only one value, int, so the compiler doesn't complain.

@user1407220 sure because in that case the return type of parent::operator() can be determined at compile time. But I don't see how it can be generalized.

I can't see it either. But the problem is not to uncommon. It occurs when building data frame (e.g. std::vector<parent> z) and one wants to access element z[0][0].

Elements of std::vector<parent> are all of type parent, not of any class derived from parent. All your dynamic_casts would fail anyway. See also: object slicing

Sorry, here is the correct version: std::vector<std::shared_ptr<parent>> z

What does "build a data frame" mean to you? What do you plan to do with the result of z[0][0] (or, I suppose, (*z[0])(0))? Again, take a step back, show the problem you are trying to solve, not the proposed solution that doesn't work. Imagine you somehow got your approach to work - show an example of how you would use it.

@IgorTandetnik: I have reworked the post and hopefully it is more clear what the problem is.

If the task is to print the elements, then have a printElement(ostream&, int) virtual function in parent and override it in child.

........... that is only an example. The task is to access the element, print it, override it, whatever.

The concept in the top of your question (where you expect auto & parent::operator() to dynamically return the proper type) - cannot work.
The return type of parent::operator() must be detemined at compile time. auto cannot perform magic, it just allows us to count on the compiler to deduce the actual type.
In your implementation the return type of parent::operator() can be either int& or double& depending on the type of derived class determined at run-time (dynamic_cast is a runtime feature). So the compiler issues an error.
Another way to looks at it:
In this statement:
std::cout<<(*X)(0)<<std::endl;

The type of the expression (*X)(0) must be determined at compile time, in order to select the proper overload of operator<< for the ostream. But it cannot because you attempt to make it one of several types, dependening on dynamic_cast.
